# Why does an exception from an FFI appear to occur, but results in an empty lefts list?

Tags: haskell, exception

First, I don't have an easy to reproduce example on hand, as the code is calling out to a MATLAB engine, which requires a license. It may be possible to construct a similar example, just using C, though. I have the following snippet from a test:

```hs
  ei1 :: Either SomeException MAnyArray <- try $ engineGetVar eng foopi
  putStrLn $ assert (isRight ei1) "  Can clearVar once"
  clearVar eng foopi
  ei2 :: Either SomeException MAnyArray <- try $ engineGetVar eng foopi
  putStrLn $ assert (isLeft ei2) $
    " Can't clearVar twice: " <> (show $ lefts [ei2])
  putStrLn "  Finished testClearVar"
```

This results in the output:

```
  Can clearVar once
Error using save
Variable 'foopi' not found.

 Can't clearVar twice: []
  Finished testClearVar
```

The confusing bit is this expression, since the assertion appears to succeed (meaning that `ei2` is a `Left` value, but when calling `lefts [ei2]`, no Left values are found):

```hs
  putStrLn $ assert (isLeft ei2) $
    " Can't clearVar twice: " <> (show $ lefts [ei2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely at documentation of `assert` you will find:

> Assertions can normally be turned on or off with a compiler flag (for GHC, assertions are normally on unless optimisation is turned on with -O or the -fignore-asserts option is given). When assertions are turned off, the first argument to assert is ignored, and the second argument is returned as the result.

I assume this is a regular package you are working on and not just a file you are compiling manually with `ghc`. By default cabal will compile a project with `-O`, which means your `assert`s are simply ignored. What you need is either `-O0` or `-fno-ignore-asserts` flag added. But what I would recommend is just don't rely on `assert` at all.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I keep getting burned by it (in different ways). Usually just when I'm trying to do something quick and dirty in a test, but it never seems to work out!